# Custom aggregate function in pandas groupby

Tags: pandas, group-by, aggregate-functions, mean

I have a dataframe like following

```
    Client          Month        Amount
     ABC           201601       -4563
     BHG           201602          321
     HTD           201601       -5234
     BTD            201603         342
     ERT.            201601        234
```

I want to find how many customer's amount is in negative for every month. It should be percentage of total clients e.g 201601 month 2 clients amount is in negative and one client's amount is in positive so the ratio should be 2/3 (total clients amount in negative)/(total clients for that specific month) like wise.

I am using following code but it does not work.

```
  df.groupby('Month')['Client'].count()
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you need `mean` of boolean mask created `x<0`:

```
df = df.groupby('Month')['Amount'].apply(lambda x: 100 * (x<0).mean())
print (df)
Month
201601    100.0
201602      0.0
201603      0.0
Name: Amount, dtype: float64
```

EDIT:

```
df = df.groupby('Month')['Amount'].apply(lambda x: 100 * (x<0).mean())
print (df)
Month
201601    66.666667
201602     0.000000
201603     0.000000
Name: Amount, dtype: float64
```

---

```
df = df.groupby(['Month', 'Client'])['Amount'].apply(lambda x: 100 * (x<0).mean())
print (df)
Month   Client
201601  ABC       100.0
        HTD       100.0
201602  BHG         0.0
201603  BTD         0.0
Name: Amount, dtype: float64
```

Comment: if I groupby multiple columns does above logic will change ?

Comment: I have to test it, give me a sec.

Comment: I think it works with multiple columns also very nice.

Comment: I need a ration of clients whos amount is in negative to total no of clients for that specific month

Comment: I am not sure if understand, it need something else? Can you change sample and add desired output or explain more? Thank you.